# Problem 98 - Project Euler

Tags: anagram

The problem is as follows:

By replacing each of the letters in the word CARE with 1, 2, 9, and 6 respectively, we form a square number: 1296 = 36^(2). What is remarkable is that, by using the same digital substitutions, the anagram, RACE, also forms a square number: 9216 = 96^(2). We shall call CARE (and RACE) a square anagram word pair and specify further that leading zeroes are not permitted, neither may a different letter have the same digital value as another letter.

Using words.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 16K text file containing nearly two-thousand common English words, find all the square anagram word pairs (a palindromic word is NOT considered to be an anagram of itself).

What is the largest square number formed by any member of such a pair?

NOTE: All anagrams formed must be contained in the given text file.

I don't understand the mapping of CARE to 1296? How does that work? or are all permutation mappings meant to be tried i.e. all letters to 1-9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: yes, all permutations need to be tried.

Answer (score 5):

All assignments of digits to letters are allowed. So C=1, A=2, R=3, E=4 would be a possible assignment ... except that 1234 is not a square, so that would be no good.

Maybe another example would help make it clear? If we assign A=6, E=5, T=2, then **TEA** = 256 = 16² and **EAT** = 625 = 25². So (TEA=256, EAT=625) is a square anagram word pair.

(Just because all assignments of digits to letters are allowed, does not mean that actually trying out all such assignments is the best way to solve the problem. There may be some other, cleverer, way to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you test all substitutions letter for digit, than you are looking for pairs of squares with properties:

- have same length
- have same digits with number of occurrences as in input string.

It is faster to find all these pairs of squares. There are 68 squares with length 4, 216 squares with length 5, ... Filtering all squares of same length by upper properties will generate 'small' number of pairs, which are solutions you are looking for.

These data is 'static', and doesn't depend on input strings. It can be calculated once and used for all input strings.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  How to put this.  The people who put together Project Euler promise that there is a solution that is under one minute for every problem, and there is only one problem that I think might fail this promise, but this is not it.

Yes, you could permute the digits, and try all permutations against all squares, but that would be a very large search space, not at all likely to be the (TM) right thing.  In general, when you see that your "look" at the problem is going to generate a search that will take too long, you need to search something else.

Like, suppose you were asked to determine what numbers would be the result of multiplying two  primes between 1 and a zillion.  You could factor every number between 1 and a zillion, but it might be faster to take all combinations of two primes and multiply them. Since you are looking at combinations, you can start with two and go until your results are too large, then do the same with three, etc. By comparison, this should be much faster - and you don't have to multiply all the numbers out, you could take logs of all the primes and then just add them and find the limit for every prime, giving you a list of numbers you could add up.

There are a bunch of innovative solutions, but the first one you think of - especially the one you think of when Project Euler describes the problem, is likely to be wrong.

So, how can you approach this problem?  There are probably too many permutations to look at, but maybe you can figure out something with mappings and comparing mappings?

(Trying to avoid giving it all away.)